# Views tagging question (bulk update tags)

Tags: views

We have a few taxonomies and don't want users to spend time tagging content. Ideally, we would like to have a view where we could tag content without opening each node.

A module exists for exactly this purpose in D6 but nothing in D7.

http://drupal.org/files/images/views_tagger_screenshot.png

Is there any other way to accomplish this??

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution, via the [editablefields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields) module!! Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows CCK fields to be edited on a node's display (e.g. at node/123), not just on the node edit pages (e.g. node/123/edit). It also works within views etc. Anywhere a 'formatter' can be selected, you can select editable (or click to edit).